# Getting product weight in magento

Tags: php, magento, csv

I'm trying to make a csv export script, for a partener price aggregation sistem. i'm having trouble extracting the weight of the products from magento.

```
$show_prodweight = (@$_GET['weight'] == "on") ? "on" : "off";
....
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setStoreId($storeId);
$product->load($product_id);

$prod_model = $product->getSku();   
$prod_id = $product->getId();
$prod_name = $product->getName();

if ( $show_prodweight =="on") {
    $prod_weight = $product->getWeight ();
    }
    else {
    $prod_weight == "2";
    }
....
print $PRODUCT['prod_weight'] . $datafeed_separator .
```

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Why it is space in function call `getWeight ();` ?

Comment: upsss type mistake, sry :)

Comment: Hope it solves your problem ?

Comment: nope, the weight field in the csv is still empty

Comment: Check the value of `var_dump($prod_weight);` in your code.

Answer (score 4):

resolved it by simplyfing code

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setStoreId($storeId);
$product->load($product_id);

$prod_model = $product->getSku();   
$prod_id = $product->getId();
$prod_name = $product->getName();
$prod_weight = $product->getWeight();
```